# How likely it is to miss a booked room in a hotel due to a storm in Iceland?

Tags: bookings, weather-and-climate, iceland

In winter it is low season so I guess there should be available rooms in the hotels. I don't care about booking or not booking rooms, but I've read that you could get stuck in the road ring due to a blizzard, and I don't want to throw away my money.

Comment: No, just a question of how common are they, or if you could assume day long held up as an every day thing

Comment: I was refering to something like this: http://luxeadventuretraveler.com/tips-for-driving-icelands-ring-road-winter/ or this: http://www.anxiousadventurers.com/practical-tips-winter-driving-iceland/ Our idea is to go one night in each hotel and go round the island for a week.

Comment: The hotels that are open have fewer visitors, but that is compensated by the fact that many fewer places to stay are open. So it is less likely that you will find a hotel when you walk in late in the afternoon or evening. I have not been on Iceland in the winter, I did not run into bad weather. My friends were there in summer and had days driving was difficult due to strong cold winds, I would not risk going round the island in a week any time of the year, much less in winter.

Comment: Based on my experience of one trip to Iceland, the likelihood is 100%. Plan accordingly.

Comment: I don't believe this is answerable objectively, it'll just come down to opinions or anecdotes. As such, I'm voting to close.  Happy to discuss if someone feels they have an objective way to answer it.

Comment: Should I delete de question? or what do I have to do to close the question?